# How fix Unable to resolve module REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

im building a musicplayer and im using `react-native-track-player`, the problem now is that in `package.json` i edited `react-native-track-player: ^1.2.3` for  `"react-native-track-player": "git://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player.git#dev"`, then I deleted the `node_modules` folder and the `build` folder of android, and ran `npm i and build` after everything was installed, i ran metro `npm start` and it gives this error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-track-player` from `index.js`: react-native-track-player could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the "advice" shown in the error message :) ?

Comment: dont know what you mean, this error just come out when I already installed the branch and run npm start

Comment: I mean try all suggestions in the error in <try these steps> ... cause it could be caching issue...

Comment: tried to run watchman watch-del-all and it says that watchman does not recognized as a internal or external command, same for rm -rf node_modules

Comment: Where did run it? I mean the path ... Is it in the project-root-folder ?

Comment: yeah, c:\user\User\project_folder> watchman del-all and also tried in  c:\user\User\project_folder>android> watchman del-all

Comment: Delete node-modules folder manually, and install it using **yarn** <Make sure the metro bundler is not running> ... then run ` yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: should I use yarn? i have always used npm

Comment: `yarn` is more reliable and has less issues **personal opinion**